# C# How to create setter in runtime?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, runtime, setter

Is there any way to add a setter in Property object such like

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Test { get; }
}
```

And I want to do it later in **runtime** using Reflection or something like this.

Comment: I don't think you can compile such an auto-property without setter

Comment: Why not a private setter?

Comment: The problem is that MyClass is not actually my class :) It's compiled DLL in my references

Comment: this is simply not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: no.

You cannot monkey-patch types in .NET, so no, you cannot do this. If the existing set mechanism is `protected`, the closest you could do would be to subclass and use member-hiding to re-declare the property with a public `set`. However, that will only be available to code that references the subclass - so: not much point.

Comment: So maybe I can change an existing getter?

Comment: @user853574 no, you cannot